# How do you know where you're already a thane?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have become thane in half the cities in Skyrim, but after playing so long I do not recall in which ones.

How do I find out which cities I still have to do some quests to become thane?

Comment: Kill someone and see if you can get away with it.

Comment: That's probably the fastest way, though not the most practical...

Comment: Getting caught pickpocketing is safer and faster.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Never thought of that myself.

Comment: take an inventory of all your thane equipment, if you didn't sell it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the easiest way to know if you're a Thane in a given Hold, is to see if you have a Housecarl there.  (This presumes you haven't taken them with you into battle already, and left them behind or gotten them killed.)  Usually, your Housecarl will be waiting for you in your house, or in the Jarl's hall if you don't have a house.

Comment: The housecarls can die? I've seen Lydia nearly and pass out dozens of time, and have run away from battle leaving her to die as cannon fodder quite a few times as well - and she always comes back after a while.

Comment: Unfortunatly, not all Holds give you a Housecarl. [F5], commit a crime, read options from guard, [F9] is the easist way for me, as suggested earlier by others.

Comment: @configurator I don't know for sure.  I just always presumed.  Never took mine into battle.

Comment: @Aida Which holds don't give you a Housecarl?  I know you can buy a house without becoming Thane, but I thought one of the standard benefits of being Thane was a Housecarl.

Comment: @Iszi Morthal, Falkreath, Winterhold, and Dawnstar don't have houses so they don't have Housecarls.

Comment: it is very possible for the housecarls to die...I lost lydia in battle..though it's hard to do.

Comment: I lost Lydia as well, against a very powerful enemy. RIP. As for seeing what cities you're Thane in, Im curious as well.

Comment: If "dead" housecarls get hit one more time, they will permanently die. Also if you kill them they will die permanently without recovering.

Comment: I think the information that housecarls can die is slightly inaccurate.  As far as I can tell the only way for a housecarl to die while they're your companion is if you deliver the killing damage, although on one occasion it seemed like if I ran away from a fight where Lydia was in mortal danger when I came back she was dead. That said I may have inadvertently killed her before I ran.

Comment: If you have Hearthfire installed, you can get a housecarl in every hold except for in Winterhold. 3 potential followers at the college, though.

Answer (score 4):

Save the game in each city, commit a crime (punch a guard), and see if the guard gives you the option to play your Thane Get Out Of Jail Free card. This assumes you haven't used the card in any city yet.

Answer (score 1):

Every thane receives a housecarl, although you have to do the civil war quest line in a certain way for Moredeth's houscarl.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know if you're a Thane is if you have a housecarl. You will only get a housecarl when you're a Thane. Another way [Though this doesn't go with all the holds, so don't blame me] is that if you have to option to buy a house if you haven't. You can also commit a crime, yield, and if you see the option to spare the guards because you're Thane, pick that option.